# NDSolve::ndnum for initial value problem of 2nd order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I have this code, which I think should work fine

```
Param = {Mo -> 112, mu1 -> 275.52,k -> 4.144,m2 -> 14,m3 -> 24, m4 -> 12, 
         R3 -> 0.16, r3 -> 0.12, rho3 -> 0.14, r1 -> 0.06};
eq = (m3*r1^2 + m3 *(r1*(r3+R3)/(2*r3+R3)) ^2 + m3*rho3*(r1/(2*r3+R3))^2 + 
      m4*(r1*(r3+R3)/(2*r3+R3))^2)*(phi1''[t]*Sin[phi1[t]]^2 - 
      0.5*phi1'[t]*Sin[phi1[t]]*Cos[phi1[t]]);
Q = Mo - k*phi1'[t] + mu1*phi1'[t]*4*(r1*(r3+R3)/(2*r3+R3));
sol = NDSolve [{eq==Q, phi1[0] == 0, phi1'[0] == 23.375} /.Param,
               {phi1},{t, 0,0.2688}]
```

However, it gives me warning

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.

There are a lot of similar questions, but none of them were helpful since I don't understand what that error means and what causes it. I believe it has something to do with `phi1[t]` being inside a sine function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let see what happens to the ode at $t=0$

In your case

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Param = {Mo -> 112, mu1 -> 275.52, k -> 4.144, m2 -> 14, m3 -> 24, 
  m4 -> 12, R3 -> 0.16, r3 -> 0.12, rho3 -> 0.14, r1 -> 0.06}
eq = (m3*r1^2 + m3*(r1*(r3 + R3)/(2*r3 + R3))^2 + 
    m3*rho3*(r1/(2*r3 + R3))^2 + 
    m4*(r1*(r3 + R3)/(2*r3 + R3))^2)*(phi1''[t]*Sin[phi1[t]]^2 - 
    0.5*phi1'[t]*Sin[phi1[t]]*Cos[phi1[t]])
Q = Mo - k*phi1'[t] + mu1*phi1'[t]*4*(r1*(r3 + R3)/(2*r3 + R3));
ode = eq == Q 
ode = ode /. Param // Rationalize
ode = First@ode - Last@ode == 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that at $t=0$ the above reduces to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Because `phi1[t]=0` at $t=0$, and hence $\sin(0)=0$ so all of the last term goes away.

Now lets apply the other initial condition which is `phi1'[0]== 187/8` and see if it satisfies the above at $t=0$

```
ode /. phi1[t] -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
% /. phi1'[t] -> Rationalize[23.375]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So at $t=0$, the initial conditions are not consistent with the ode.

So I think the problem is that your initial conditions are not consistent. Normally `NDSolve` will say that as another warning message [ibcinc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NDSolve/ibcinc.html) , but may be in this case it did not?

Comment: `ibcinc` is only for PDE. If we force `NDSolve` to use `"Residual"` method for equation simplification, we'll see `ivres` warning. (See my answer for more info. )

Answer (score 2):

The problem is strongly related to e.g.

[Numerical solution of Bessel-like equation using NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34423/1871)

[NDSolve divide-by-zero trouble](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102305/1871)

[Trouble in the second order ordinary differential equations with second oder coupled iterm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210014/1871)

But it may be hard for beginners to notice the underlying relationship, so let me elaborate a bit. As discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871), `NDSolve` by default transforms the ODE to a first order system in *standard form*. This standard form can be obtained with [`to1storder`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132713/1871):

```
internalsys = 
 to1storder[eq == Q /. Param, phi1, t, "standardize" -> True, "form" -> Subscript]
```

[image]

As shown above, the standard form involves a `Csc[Subscript[phi1, 0][t]]` term. (`Subscript[phi1, 0]` stands for `phi1` in original equation. ) So the initial condition `phi1[0] == 0` will lead to non-numerical `ComplexInfinity`:

```
internalsys[[1]] /. t -> 0 /. Subscript[phi1, 0][0] -> 0
(* {Subscript[phi1, 1]'[0] == ComplexInfinity} *)
```

This is the reason why `ndnum` warning pops up.

The `ndnum` warning can be circumvented by, as discussed in linked posts above, `SolveDelayed -> True`:

```
NDSolve[{eq == Q, phi1[0] == 0, phi1'[0] == 23.375} /. Param, {phi1}, {t, 0, 0.2688},
  SolveDelayed -> True]
```

But this leads to the warning

> NDSolve::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended.

The reason is already elaborated in [Nasser's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/278474/1871), so I'd like not to repeat. You should double check the underlying model of your equation.